# apache2 permissions denied, django project

Tags: django, linux, pdf, apache2, reportlab

I have a linux server (ubuntu) and I uploaded a project, in my project, I try to generate a pdf with reportlab, using some fonts for the created pdf.
I am having problems with permissions for reportlab. When I check out the error log in apache (/var/log/apache2/error.log), the error that appears is:

reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts.TTFError: Can't open file "recursos/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf"

I already gave full permissions (chmod 777) and also changed the owner to apache (chown :www-data) to the whole project, but the same error appears.

In my local machine, works perfectly.

Comment: Does the file exist in the file path?

Comment: how I solved it, was using the os.path(BASE_DIR,"corresponding path of the font") I don't know why just adding the path without the os.path didn't work, but adding the os.path worked correctly. Thank you